# Kill event thread

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading, events

I have a timer event that fires every second. Sometimes when I exit the program (in the VS debugger), it tells me that the event thread is trying to access an object that no longer exists (because the main thread is over). I tried disabling the event before I exit (`UpdateTime.aTimer.Enabled = false;`). This cut down the number of times this problem occurs, but it still happens sometimes because the event fires before I can disable it.

1. Is this a serious problem?  Will is haunt me if I don't deal with it?
2. If yes to the above, how do I kill it?

I ask the second question because I have no reference to the event thread, so I don't know how I can tell it to stop or wait for it to finish.

EDIT: More context. This is a Winform.

Also, I'm not explicitly creating a thread. It's my understanding that a thread is automatically created to handle events.

Creating the timer:

```
public static void Update(){

    System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
    aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
    aTimer.Enabled = true;

}
```

Event handler:

```
private static void OnTimedEvent(object source,ElapsedEventArgs e) {

    Form1obj.updateLabel(String.Format("{0}", DateTime.Now.Second),Label1);

}
```

Closing program handler:

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender,FormClosingEventArgs e) {

    aTimer.Enabled = false;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Serious Problem? Probably not, but I don't think a problem needs to be serious to need to be fixed. Warnings should be treated as errors in compilation, for example. In addition, if this is an app sent to clients, showing ugly errors on shutdown is not very professional.

How to solve this depends on how you are setting up the threads ("event thread" does not give enough info about the mechanics). One easy method might be to stall the main thread for a bit when the application shuts down until the threads all return. You have to also stop issuing new threads during this time.

Another possible solution would be to handle how the threads are created so you can shut down the process that fires them. Concepts like ThreadPool come to mind. Also ensuring threads are background threads, explicitly, can help in some situations.

The short answer is nobody will be able to give you a firm "this will fix your issue" answer without some context of what you are doing in your code.

ADDED:

There are a couple of "quick, down and dirty" ways to handle this. Don't have time for full analysis, so see if they work.

1. Just cure the error by waiting
2. Add a counter and wait until incremented down

The first thing I would consider is adding a safety net to not update the label when in a shutdown condition. That is regardless of anything else, as that is where your errors are firing. I don't think "main thread is not present" is the core of the issue, but rather this line:

```
Form1obj.updateLabel(String.Format("{0}", DateTime.Now.Second),Label1);
```

How can you update something that no longer exists? Yes, it is on the main thread, so technically ...

A simple wait would be something like:

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender,FormClosingEventArgs e) 
{
     aTimer.Enabled = false;  
     Thread.Sleep(5000);
}
```

Hiding the form is also not a bad idea, so the user does not see this?

If you want to use a more "COM like approach", you can add a counter. Increment on Update() (when the event is fired) and decrement on OnTimedEvent(). Make sure you lock the counter when changing it so you do not end up with two threads changing it at the same millisecond. You can then wait until the counter is 0 to finish form close or application unload.

Once again, these are quick, down and dirty, approaches, but they can save you from the error. I am sure someone with more time can come up with a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can close the window [as suggested in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.elapsed.aspx) - when you set the timer to be disabled during shutdown processing, set a flag that your `Elapsed` event handler can check to know that no more work is needed.

> Elapsed events can occur after the
>   Dispose or Stop method has been called
>   or after the Enabled property has been
>   set to false, because the signal to
>   raise the Elapsed event is always
>   queued for execution on a thread pool
>   thread. One way to resolve this race
>   condition
>   is to set a flag that tells the event
>   handler for the Elapsed event to
>   ignore subsequent events.

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to give a general awnser to the question if its serious or not, it depends entiry on what the timer is doing. what kind of timer is it? a system.Threading one or one of the UI timers?

If possible try and refactor your code so that you can tell the timer to stop firing, if only for the reason not to confuse the users with an error message. it could be as simple as sharing a variable or (preferably) using a [CancellationToken](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321629.aspx)